# PHP session not persisting between screens

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

I have come across an issue that has confused me a lot. 
I am working on a login screen using PHP and MySQL. I manage to validate the username and password against an existing user in the database and after this, I initiate a session, and set the session variable username to the username provided in the login screen.

```
    $username = html($_POST['username']);
    $password = html($_POST['password']);

    $result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username  AND    password = :password');
    $result->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $result->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $result->execute();

    foreach($result as $user)
    {
        $count = $count + 1;
    }

    if ($count == 1)
    {
              session_start();
          $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
       ` //if I do an echo $_SESSION['username'] it displays the correct user
          header('Location: .');
          exit();`
    }
```

However when it transfers me to the index.php page the `$_SESSION['username']` variable has disappeared and I do not understand why. This is the code I use in index.php to check for the username:

```
<p><a href="view.php">View all tasks</a></p>
<p><a href="form.php?add">Add your own task</a></p>

<p>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>
```

however I get the following error: `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\abcabcabc\index.php on line 16`

All advice will be greatly appreciated guys

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` on each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`sesssion_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) to all of your scripts that use the session

Comment: to each page? I thought that `session_start()` was only needed once where I start the session and initialise the session variables?

Comment: From php.net: "session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie."

Comment: I believe this has solved my issue. I didn't know i had to use it on every page that uses the session variables. I thought this would reset the session altogether

Comment: Will choose as answer as soon as it lets me do so. Thank you for the prompt reply

Answer (score 0):

You must use `session_start();` at the beginning of index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 answers are correct. You must start session on each page. I usually just put it in a file that is "included" in every page already (like a header file) so I don't have to think about it.

Comment: this is a very good suggestion Joel. I might do this because I am including certain files on each page. Are there any known advantages to this approach or is it used because you "write once" and forget about it rather than having to remember to add it to every page?

Comment: It needs to be there and it seems to be a logical place to put it. I am not aware of any other specific advantages.